# What are the differences between system properties and application properties in azure-iot-hub message?

Tags: azure-iot-sdk

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct) contains Create and read IoT Hub messages of azure. 
 I'm confused about `app property` and `message property`. 
What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of system properties is predetermined - in some cases the values are not user settable. Typically, system properties are used by IoT Hub as part of IoT Hub's standard message processing.
You can create and set any application properties for your own purposes - application properties may be used as part of any custom routing rules you create in your hub. You may also want to use your custom application properties in any downstream D2C message processing in your solution.

An example of a system property is `iothub-connection-device-id` - this property is set by IoT Hub on every D2C message. This property contains the id of the device that sent the message and cannot be changed.

An example of an application property might be `severity`. You could then use the values (such as `info`, `warning`, and `error`) to route messages to different endpoints.

Comment: thanks for your response , could you please give any examples for both .

Comment: I added a couple of examples to the answer above.

Comment: Thank you @Dominic Betts got it